# How to get device manufacturer keystore certificate in android

Tags: android, apk, keystore, sign

How can I get device manufacturer keystore certificate to sign an app with apksign.jar in Android?

Comment: I rather doubt they will simply send that to you.

Comment: Hi, did you find way to install app without prompt user, or did you got sign certificate if yes please let me know i need the same.

Answer (score 7):

> How to get device manufacturer keystore certificate to sign app with apksign.jar in android

Buy lots of guns and take hostages, with part of your ransom demands being that you are given the device manufacturer's firmware signing key. Note that this technique will be against the law in various jurisdictions.

Otherwise, no device manufacturer with a gram of common sense will hand over their firmware signing key.

You are welcome to sign your own ROM mod with your own signing key, in which case you can then use that signing key to sign other apps.

Comment: Occasionally if you have enough pull, a valid reason, and a multi 100 thousand dollar bond, they may allow you to submit your application for them to sign for you.

Comment: @draksia: Agreed on the flow -- you give them the app, they sign it. Usually, I only see that for apps that will be pre-loaded on the device. I can certainly see a manufacturer extending that to some major enterprise as part of a bulk purchase deal, and with some sort of bond as you mention.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to compile and sign an APK with a certificate belonging to another entity (such as the device manufacturer) you will have to contact that device manufacturer.

If you are trying to compile and sign your own app before you upload to the play store you can generate your own certificate.

Comment: i don't upload app to play store.

Comment: Why are you trying to sign your APK?

Comment: Any other way is there?

Comment: Because i want to install multiple apk in device from my one app without prompt, so i want that.

Comment: An APK is an app. So you are trying to have your app install another app? I'm pretty sure this is prohibited by Google. The scenario you are describing could be used to install spyware or malware.

Comment: I want to install apk from device storage not from cloud.

Comment: You can sign with your own key

Comment: ya but then it can not install silently without prompt

Comment: why do you want to install an app without the user knowing?

Comment: I know I'm late for the party, but a valid reason for doing silent installs is if you are writing a client for a MDM (Mobile Device Management Tool).